# Use a differential to estimate to estimate the given quantity.

Tags: calculus

Use a differential to estimate to estimate $$10^{1.1}$$considering $\ln 10\approx 2.30$ and $e \approx 2.72$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: tried to somehow relate it to $(b^{x})'=b ln (b)$ but I got stuck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $f(x) = 10^x$ then $f'(x) = 10^x\log(n)$, so $f(1) = 10$ and $f'(1) \approx 23$  Now use a tangent line approximation
$$f(1.1) \approx f(1) + f'(1)(1.1 - 1) = 10 + 23(.1) = 12.3$$
This function is concave up, so the tangent line method gives an underestimate. The actual value is 12.59.